# Can I include a method call inside a LINQ statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code:

```
            var webWordForms = rootObject.webWordForms
                .Where(w => w.definition != null)
                .ToList();

            foreach (var webWordForm in rootObject.webWordForms)
            {   
                    processWordForm(word, webWordForm);               
            }
```

Is there a way that I can combine these two statements and call processWordForm from inside the first statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `ForEach` extension on `List<T>`

For example,

```
rootObject.webWordForms
                .Where(w => w.definition != null)
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(webWordForm => processWordForm(word, webWordForm));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ForEach` method of List to chain your operation, but it is not different than what you are already doing.

```
 tObject.webWordForms
        .Where(w => w.definition != null)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(wordForm => processWordForm(word, wordForm));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I feel I should award this to Colin as his answer came in a minute before yours. I have upvoted your answer.